# How can I add jQuery to DOM element through drupal.behaviours?

Tags: 8, javascript

On my site on the navigation panel I have a dropdown language switcher. (Dropdown Language Switcher module). I need to modify the js file and show the message to the user after he switched the language. What is the right way to modify js file?

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
'use strict';

Drupal.behaviors.dropdownLanguagesSelector = {
  attach: function(context, settings) {
   $('.dropdown-language-item .active-language', context).once('dropdown-language-selector')
    .click(function(e) {
      var $wrapper = $(this).closest('.dropbutton-wrapper');
      if ($wrapper.length > 0) {
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();
        $wrapper.toggleClass('open');
      }
    });
  }
};
})(jQuery, Drupal);
```

Language switcher HTML looks like following:

```
<div class="dropbutton-widget">
 <ul class="dropdown-language-item dropbutton">
  <li class="fr dropbutton-action">
   <span class="language-link active-language" hreflang="fr">FR</span></li> 
  <li class="dropbutton-toggle"></li>
  <li class="en dropbutton-action secondary-action"></li>
  <li class="de dropbutton-action secondary-action"></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I am trying to attach following event:

```
$('.secondary-action').click(function(){
   alert(Message!);
})
```

Comment: Is the JS you showed at the start of the post working as you've shown it?

Comment: It is a contributed module. This js came with the package

Comment: Ok, you wouldn't change that file then. You would use the code structure I gave below (which I'll update slightly according to your reply)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a skeleton of how you can add functionality to elements using Drupal.behaviors.

```
(function ($, Drupal) {
  'use strict';

  // Create a new function for each element the file attaches
  // handlers to. In this case, $(.secondary-action')
  function secondaryEventListener(context) {
    // Find the elements, ensure that any internal code is executed
    // a single time using $.once(), then loop through the found elements
    // using $.each()
    $(context).find('.secondary-action').once('secondary-event-listener').each(function () {
      // $(this) refers to the current instance of $('secondary-action')
      $(this).click(function () {
        alert("clicked");
      });
    });
  }

  Drupal.behaviors.someArbitraryButUniqueKey = {
    attach: function(context, settings) {
      // Call your function containing the handlers
      secondaryEventListener(context);
    }
  };
}(jQuery, Drupal));
```

Comment: Should I put this code in the separate file?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. You can look at how to include the file in Drupal here: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/javascript-api/javascript-api-overview